# String filtering in SparkR

Tags: r, sparkr

I have a simple Spark data frame strings and I cannot filter it by using the `str_count` function in the `stringr` package. For example:

```
> library(stringr)
> df = data.frame(long=c("AA", "BB"), short=c("A", "B"))
> df
  long short
1   AA     A
2   BB     B 
> sdf = as.DataFrame(df)
> filter(sdf, str_count(sdf$long, "A") == 2)
Error in if (length(string) == 0) return(character()) : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
```

I suspect there is some problem with the type conversions but I cannot find a solution. The `subset` function and the "array selection" notation fail as well.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you create "sdf"? df is already a dataframe, and the code you use to declare sdf is not correct (it should be "*as.data.frame(df)*")

Then, I don't get any error in the filter code you're using.

Comment: sdf is a Spark data frame. The first is just a normal R data frame

Answer (score 0):

To convert normal R data frame to Spark data frame, use this line of code.

```
sdf <- as.data.frame(df)
```

And coming to this line of code

```
filter(sdf, str_count(sdf$long, "A") == 2)
```

`str_count(sdf$long, "A") == 2`, this line is perfectly fine and returns `c(TRUE, FALSE)`

If you want to print data based on the above line, I would suggest to use this line of code

```
sdf[str_count(sdf$long, "A") == 2]
```

which gives you the output (assuming this is your expected result)

```
  long
1   AA
2   BB
```

rather than `filter(sdf, str_count(sdf$long, "A") == 2)`, because condition part in filter doesn't accept logical TRUE or FALSE

Comment: The function `SparkR::as.data.frame` converts from SparkDataFrame to normal R data.frame, so your string operation is not happening in spark.